# Query of multi level in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I have a Category / Products / Users
I need to get all Categories of All Products for a specific user.
I was able to make selecting a product for a specific User but I couldn't tell how to get all the categories of these products.

Products and Users relationship is ManyToMany.
The relationship between product belongsTo Category and Category hasMany Products

Here is what I made:

```
$products = Product::byUser(auth()->id())->get();

public function scopeByUser(Builder $query)
{
    return $query->whereHas('users', function ($q) {
        $q->where('id', auth()->id());
    });
}
```

But I couldn't make it in a way to have:

```
$products = Category::productsByUser(auth()->id());
```

So that I can get all the categories and all the products of the loggedIn user.

Thank you,

Comment: It sounds like what you want to do is load the categories relationship for the products associated to your user. Unless you want the categories listed separately from the products then it would be where has product with a nested where has user to get your productByUser function working

Comment: Can you type me a code sample to understand what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either load the categories with the products in a single query to get a list of the products associated to a user. Or you can create a scope filter on the category model to return a list of categories associated with products that are associated with the user:

**Load categories with() products:**

[Eager Loading Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
$products = Product::with('categories')->byUser(auth()->user()->id)->get();
```

This will return a collection of products which already have the related categories loaded so you can call $products->first()->categories()->get() to return a list of the categories for that product.

**Use a scope filter on the Category Model to list categories only:**

[Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes)

```
public function scopeByUser(Builder $query, $user_id)
{
    return $query->whereHas('products', function ($q) use($user_id) {
        $q->whereHas('user', function ($q) use($user_id){
            $q->where('id', $user_id);
        }
    });
}
```

Then you can run Category::byUser(auth()->user()->id)->get(); to return a collection of categories which are associated to products which are associated to user id given.

**UPDATE: Conditional Eager Loading with Scope filter**

You still want to user eager loading with a condition to load all products which are associated to the user and then apply the above scope filter to limit the categories returned to only be those associated to the user:

```
$user_id = auth()->user()->id;
$categories = Category::with(['products'=> function($q) use($user_id){
    $q->whereHas('user',function($q) use($user_id){
        $q->where('id',$user_id);
    });
}])->byUser($user_id)->get()
```

This will return a collection of Categories which are associated to products which are associated to the provided user id and will eager load products for the category if those products are associated with the user id provided.

Comment: Category::byUser(auth()->id)->get();
Returns only the Categories that associated with products which are associated with a user without getting the products.
Isn't there a way to get the products as well?.

Comment: you cant get a separate list of products and categories with one query on an eloquent model. you would have to run two. The best way to get both from one query on a model would be to use eager loading and then you could get the combined list of categories from the products collection:

foreach($products as $p){ if($categories){ $categories = $categories->merge($p->categories()->get() }else{ $categories = $p->categories()->get()}}
$categories = $categories->unique();

Comment: What I am looking for is a Collection of
Categories -> each category have all the products related to this category with the condition of getting only the products that are related to a specific user.

So it's not like two Collections, it's just one>

Comment: oh your question didnt read like that. I'll update my answer but its basically the combination of both answers

Comment: The updated "Conditional Eager Loading with Scope filter" approach should provide the collection of categories with the correct products eager loaded based on the association with the user

Comment: Perfect Answer.  Thank you.